# how to find a function with RTN_FindByName?

Tags: c++, linux, intel, intel-pin

i am struggling On finding a function with prototype `mul(float,float)` i try to use `RTN_FindByName` but the output is still empty.

```
VOID Arg1Before(CHAR * name, ADDRINT size)
{
    TraceFile << name << "(" << size << ")" << endl;
}
VOID MulAfter(ADDRINT ret)
{
    TraceFile << "  returns " << ret << endl;
}
VOID Image(IMG img, VOID *v)
{
// Instrument the mul() and div() functions.  Print the input argument
// of each mul() or div(), and the return value of mul().
//
//  Find the mul() function.
RTN mulRtn = RTN_FindByName(img, MUL);
if (RTN_Valid(mulRtn))
{
    RTN_Open(mulRtn);
    // Instrument mul() to print the input argument value and the return value.
    RTN_InsertCall(mulRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)Arg1Before,
                   IARG_ADDRINT, MUL,
                   IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0,
                   IARG_END);
    RTN_InsertCall(mulRtn, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)MulAfter,
                   IARG_FUNCRET_EXITPOINT_VALUE, IARG_END);
    RTN_Close(mulRtn);
}
}
```

There, `MUL` is a constant which is **"mul"**. Obviously, i have included pin.H. the problem is that my traceFile is still empty

Comment: However, when i look for malloc instead of my function, it works successfully. i don't understand

Comment: The function name might be decorated. Try to have a look with `objdump` or loop over all the RTNs and get their names with `RTN_Name` (andf see if you have something containing "mul" in it). Be sure sure to call `PIN_InitSymbols()` at the very start of your `main` function.

Comment: Thanks. the function was decorated as you said. so i found a way to undecorate it before usage